# One of my random effects in REML causes error

Tags: r, lme4

Thank you for your time. I have been reading through some of the threads where the error message is

> "Downdated VtV is not positive definite"

My response variable is numeric (latency to display in seconds). 
Fixed effects are sexC2, Mixed (yes or no), AscoreQ (4 categories), WinnerC1 (yes or no) 
The random effect is DyadC2, which is a factor, with a different number for each pair of animals.

This is the code I'm using:

```
lmm <- lmer(displayC2 ~ sexC2 + Mixed + WinnerC1 + AscoreQ + WinnerC1*AscoreQ + (1|DyadC2)
```

It works if I don't put in the random variable, but when I put this in, I get the output:

> "Error in fn(x, ...) : Downdated VtV is not positive definite"

Please could you let me know if you have any ideas why this is not working?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is a not a definite answer, a probable issue is that you have zero variance somewhere (for example there are all-0 or all-1 categories in the data). It is impossible to test without the data. Maybe this [discusion](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/173) could help you.